# Calculation of unit mass of beam shell by using patran or nastran

Tags: modeling, simulation

I would like to know how to calculate unit mass of beam having uniform cross section, made by shell, by using Patran or Nastran, not by manual.

Would there be any functions to calculate mass or unit mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Nastran using the **Grid point weight generator** option. Look up PARAM,GRDPNT in the documentation.

Patran probably has something equivalent, but the Nastran output is "guaranteed" to be consistent with the model that you actually analysed.